# Generated system.img not running on emulator

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, android-source, android-tv

I wanted to build a custom ROM for Android TV.

I have followed the steps given on the [Android Source Code - AOSP website](https://source.android.com/?hl=es-419) and downloaded the source using the commands below:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
repo sync -j16 -c

source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86-eng
```

To build the system image, I am using the following command:

```
make -j16
```

It is using the latest Q release to build:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=Q
PLATFORM_VERSION=Q
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=LiveTv
TARGET_ARCH=x86
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-130-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-16.04.4-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OC-MR1
OUT_DIR=out
```

The build is always successful. `system.img` and `ramdisk.img` are also generated.

I wanted to test the system image on an emulator. I used the command below:

```
./emulator -avd tvrom -sysdir out/target/product/generic_x86/ -system out/target/product/generic_x86/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic_x86/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic_x86/userdata.img -kernel prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/kernel-qemu
```

The `avd` name is `tvrom` and the other parameters are paths to the system images I have built.

But, after doing this, `system.img` is not booting in the emulator and it remains a black screen there.

Also, there is an error printing in the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I searched for it but didn't find any solution. Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**

If someone provides a list of steps to flash and boot the latest AOSP_X86 or AOSP_X86_64 customized ROM on Android Emulator, then it will be useful.

Comment: Are you using `repo sync` to download sources? If you are, you need to mention the version as a parameter.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal yes I am using repo sync -j8 -c

Comment: Sorry, I mean `repo init`. You need to specify the android version here. Check this link for more info: https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Please see updated question. I have also put bounty on the question.

Comment: Does the emulator run with other images? Like ones that are provided in Android Studio?

Comment: And if it does, the only thing I can think of right now is using `lunch goldfish` instead of `lunch aosp_x86-eng`

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal What is the difference between two? I am novice in custom roms.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Yes, It is only running with provided images in Android studio.

Comment: `goldfish` is the official device code for the Android Emulator. `aosp_x86-eng` is a general image for any x86 based device (eg. Your laptop). Truthfully, I've never been able to get the latter to work in any of my tests.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I am getting error running that: build/make/core/product_config.mk:229: error: Can not locate config makefile for product "goldfish".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176326/discussion-between-susmit-agrawal-and-agile1).

Comment: Were you able to get a fix ? i am trying to just extract an image and rebuild it and it won't run

Answer (score 0):

1. master branch is not a stable branch. Always sync an officially tagged branch.
2. The correct lunch target for an emulator is sdk_phone_x86 for 32 bit or sdk_phone_x86_64 for 64 bit.

Answer (score -2):

Verify Build Configuration:
Double-check your build configuration, especially the lunch command. Make sure you have selected the correct target for Android TV x86. You can use lunch to select the correct target:

lunch aosp_x86-eng

Use Prebuilt Kernel:
Instead of using the kernel from the prebuilts directory, you can try using the kernel provided by the emulator itself. Use the -kernel-qemu option without specifying the path:

./emulator -avd tvrom -sysdir out/target/product/generic_x86/ -system out/target/product/generic_x86/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic_x86/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic_x86/userdata.img -kernel prebuilts/qemu-kernel/x86/kernel-qemu

Use Android TV AVD:
Create an AVD specifically for Android TV. You can do this using the AVD Manager:

avdmanager create avd -n tvrom -k "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86"

Then, start the emulator using the AVD name:

emulator -avd tvrom

Rebuild and Retry:
If none of the above steps resolves the issue, you might want to clean the build and try rebuilding the ROM. Sometimes, issues can be caused by incomplete or corrupted builds.

make clean
make -j16